# NGINX - parse request body to get the correct file

Tags: nginx

I would like to configure an NGINX server to return the content of a file whose path is determined by a variable in the request body. No LUA if possible.

When the user calls the API:

```
curl -X PATCH https://myapipath/1.0.0/devices \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer beb227b4-9c1b-3b49-b86f-b48377ab8c62' \
--data-raw '{"devices":[{"deviceId":"mydeviceid","deviceType":"mydevicetype"}]}'
```

the server should return the file at this path: `mypath/mydeviceid/mydevicetype/devicedetails.json`. I've configured this location in NGINX conf, but I don't know how to add the parsing logic to get the value of `deviceId` and `deviceType` from the request body:

```
location myapipath/1.0.0/devices{alias /mypath/devicedetails.json;error_page 405 =200 $uri;}
```

Could you help me to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

nginx isn't designed to perform application logic like this.

You need to use either the Lua module or the [njs module](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/dynamic-modules/nginscript/) to implement logic like this.

Another approach is to implement the backend logic in application (PHP, Python, Ruby, Perl etc.), and then the application would return response with [X-Accel-Redirect](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/) header to tell what file nginx should send.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Unfortunately I never used LUA. How I can to do that with LUA?

Comment: I haven't done anything with Lua on nginx myself, so I cannot comment on how to do it. You can perform the task on any application language you are familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Lua in Nginx.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location = /1.0.0/devices {

            default_type application/json;
            resolver 1.1.1.1;
            set $deviceId '';
            set $deviceType '';

            rewrite_by_lua_block {

                    local json = require "cjson.safe"
                    ngx.req.read_body()
                    local body = ngx.req.get_body_data()

                    if not body then
                            ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)
                    end

                    local data, err = json.decode(body)

                    if err then
                            ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)
                    end

                    local deviceId = data.deviceId
                    local deviceType = data.deviceType
                    ngx.var.deviceId = deviceId 
                    ngx.var.deviceType = deviceType 

            }

            set $proxy_endpoint = https://api.tld/mypath/$deviceId/$deviceType/devicedetails.json;
            proxy_pass $proxy_endpoint;

    }

}
```

This

- extracts your two variables from the JSON Payloads using LUA's json parser.
- pass them to nginx
- defines a proxy path that includes your two variables

Altough this would work with a properly formatted JSON payload, there is logic to be added as to handle gracefully invalid or corrupted payloads.

**There are also security considerations : these two variables must be sanitized.**